# Will tokens with Google plus scope invalidate after API shutdown

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

Google has announced the shutdown of Google+ scopes and APIs on March 7th.

We have multiple Google scopes approved for a single refresh token so I guess my question is will the token totally invalidate after the shutdown?

For example, I have both contact scope (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds) and Google+ scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me) approved for a refresh token.

After Google plus shutdown on March 7th, will I still be able to request Google Contacts APIs with this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the refresh token has other valid scopes, they will continue to work. Essentially, the `plus.me` scope will be "removed" from the token.

Answer (score 1):

> After Google plus shutdown on March 7th, will I still be able to request Google Contacts APIs with this token?

[Contacts v3](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/) has two scopes. Depending upon what you are doing.

- https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/  read/write access to Contacts and Contact Groups
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly read-only access to Contacts and Contact Groups

As long as you are using `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/` then you will be able to use the google contacts api.  I am not sure why you are using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` as its not required by the google contacts api but any calls that you may be making using that scope will no longer work to work.

Any refresh tokens that you have should still work when calling google contacts api

Comment: Yeah I don't need this scope for Contacts API, I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me to get the user's profile (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me).  I understand that I have to change this API, but just wanted to know whether it would affect the other integration.

Comment: As i mentioned in the last like the refresh token you currently have will still have access to the scopes that are still valid.  The one that is being discontinued will no logger work.

Answer (score 1):

Today (7th March, 19) Google+ API shut down completely, I had issue in rails application with authentication and I solved it by replacing OpenIdConnect endpoint, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043208/10522579)